# \overset and superscripts

Tags: positioning, superscripts, overset

Consider this MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{align}
&\overset{0}{\mathcal{D}^{\alpha\beta}}\\
&\overset{0}{\mathcal{D}}^{\alpha\beta}
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

which gives the following (both wrong!) results:

[image]

I want the superscripts athe the level of the top of `$\mathcal{D}$` (as in the first case), but the overset `$0$`, must be only over the `$\mathcal{D}$`, not the superscripts (as in the second line).

How can I do that?

Comment: Why `\overset{0}`? Is that what you are looking for and not `\mathring`?

Comment: @Manuel No there is a `0` because there will also be `\overset{1}` ... `\overset{n}`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do that very simply with `\accentset` from the `accents` package. Note it is by default in `scriptscriptstyle`. You can force `scriptstyle`, but the documentation of the package warns you can have trouble. In the present example, it seems to work:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{accents}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
    & \accentset{0}{\mathcal{D}}^{0\alpha\beta} \\
    & \accentset{\scriptstyle 0}{\mathcal{D}}^{0\alpha\beta}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]